# Access Facebook from a C# Windows Client

Tags: c#, facebook

is there any C# Library that enables me to acces my Facebok Account from a C# Application. All I've found are ASP.Net Libraries but I don't wan't to use ASP. I wan't to create a Windows Forms or WPC Client for Facebook. Is this possible? Basically I'm looking for something like Facebook Connect on the iPhone I guess.

Thank you very much

CaptnCrash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can access the facebook API from WPF. check out the [Facebook developer kit](http://facebooktoolkit.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 1):

We recently launched a [C# SDK](http://github.com/facebook/csharp-sdk). You'll need to get the `access_token` using the [OAuth flow](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) via some interaction with a web browser and then the SDK will help you in making API calls.